# how to set selected item in ComboBox

Tags: winforms, combobox

This should be easy but Windows.Forms surprises me again:

```
        var comboBox2 = new ComboBox();
        comboBox2.Items.Insert(0,"Hoi");
        comboBox2.Items.Insert(1,"Hoi");
        comboBox2.Items.Insert(2,"Hoi");
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1;//I want to select the SECOND item
```

If I openup the combobox (by clicking on it with the mouse) the FIRST item is selected. This does not occur when the items have different texts. How can I select the second item on this combobox?

Comment: You should name your ComboBox.

Comment: I can't repro your problem using VS2008 .NET 3.5. 2nd item is correctly selected for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET WinForms ComboBox, identical items, and the SelectedIndexChanged event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354408/net-winforms-combobox-identical-items-and-the-selectedindexchanged-event)

Comment: Thanks! This is a duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this,

```
comboBox2.Items.Insert(0,"Hoi");
comboBox2.Items.Insert(1,"Hui");
comboBox2.Items.Insert(2,"Hai");
```

and after this try giving

```
comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

and also if you want select an item, always the index will starts from 0.

Comment: tried it. Has no effect. The text should be the same otherwise the problem does not occur

Comment: no, effect in the sense? Is it not selecting the second item?

Comment: Yep. When the text is the same the problem persists.

Comment: What ever may be the text, the same formula will be applied. Can you post the modified code now again?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proper datasource set the following properties:
1. DataSource
2. DisplayMember and 
3. ValueMember

If you dont have the data source, try setting the following properties:
1. SelectedIndex and 
2. Text